# Access keys from browser store using webcrypto api

Tags: javascript, security, internet-explorer, cryptography

I did find out that IE11 supports web crypto API. Is it possible to access keys in the browser store using this API via Javascript? I could not find any interfaces for this.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376560.aspx

Comment: Hello Marcus, the above link provides the C++ interface. But my query is on javascript WebCrypto API

Comment: In the future, please be sure to use the appropriate tags and be clear in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not, and likely will never be possible. Browsers are moving to a strict enforcement of the Same Origin Policy security model which is removing the mechanisms that could have been the basis of such a solutions.

Pre-provisioned "named keys", may end up being supported, as the earlier respondent indicated, but this is really most useful for DRM systems like those used by Netflix and not for provisioning cases like you are interested in.

Comment: Thank you. But i did not get the point when u say "Not for provisioning cases like you are interested in" . I did not mention any use cases am interested in. Now let me come to the use case. From what i understand from the webcrypto docs, it is mentioned for use cases such as S/MIME, web form signing etc. But what is the point in having a such a standard when there i no way one can access the keys and certificates that are pre-existing with a client. In addition to this, people are encouraged to store there keys in Crypto hardwares.The web crypto do not have any interfaces to access these keys

Comment: Sorry, I clearly made an incorrect assumption. The most common case I see when speaking to folks about this area is interactions with smart cards and of late that of keygen since it is going away. That bias came though in my read of your question. That said the answer is still the same, the keys with webcrypto are browser bound, you can not access anything outside of the browser with it and that includes smart cards or keys stored in the operating system. As for the value of browser bound keys, there are relatively few people who have client certificates today.

Comment: This combined with browsers security model where applications are only able to interact with the "same origin" as they were served from made adding support for that case a low priority. One can still implement all of the cases you mention, they just need to do so in a way that fits within the browser security model.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunatly, this is not possible. But another API ([WebCrypto Key Discovery](http://www.w3.org/TR/webcrypto-key-discovery/)), with the purpose of giving access to pre-provisioned keys within the WebCrypto, is currently under development.

As explained in the Working Draft abstract:

> This specification describes a JavaScript API for discovering named,
>   origin-specific pre-provisioned cryptographic keys for use with the
>   Web Cryptography API. Pre-provisioned keys are keys which have been
>   made available to the UA by means other than the generation,
>   derivation, importation functions of the Web Cryptography API.

But, since the process is still in an early phase, I don't think there is any browser implementing this API for the moment.